# How to set background image for sencha touch carousel indicator

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, carousel

I have application where i need to hide the default dot indicator on the carousel control, and instead for default indicator i have to replace it with customized images?

Comment: have you tried to change the CSS of `.x-carousel-indicator`? `background-image`, `background`, or smt like that? If so, what did you get?

Comment: how to set the background-image property

Comment: `.x-carousel-indicator-dark span { background-image: none; background-color: #8B3626; }`. Have you tried to replace `background-image:none;` to some image url? Try it out and tell us what you've given

Comment: I have given like this   background-image: 'url(http://icons.mysitemyway.com/wp-content/gallery/simple-red-square-icons-arrows/128403-simple-red-square-icon-arrows-arrow-redo.png)'; its throwing error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can inspect the CSS for the indicator object.
For instance, go to the [Kitchen Sink > User Interface > Carousel](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/examples/production/kitchensink/#demo/carousel) and inspect one of the dots :

```
.x-carousel-indicator span {
  display: block;
  width: .5em;
  height: .5em;
  -webkit-border-radius: .25em;
  border-radius: .25em;
  margin: .2em;
}
```

Then, you just need to override that CSS class

Answer (score 2):

To hide the default dot `indicator` in `Ext.carousel.Carousel` component, use this,

```
indicator: false
```

Comment: Ya i got that thanks for the reply, how do we replace that indicator with some background image

Comment: There's no built-in property to achieve this. You'll have to write your custom carousel for it.

Comment: They have given some css like /* line 34, ../themes/stylesheets/sencha-touch/default/widgets/_carousel.scss */
.x-carousel-indicator-dark span {
  background-image: none;
  background-color: #8B3626;
}                                                                    i am wondering how to set background-image , i am not finding any examples to do so.